# Class methods: When to pass arguments and when to use properties?

Tags: php, oop

I'm a little bit confused here, and all examples I found on Google are in others languages and I get even more confused.

Should I define my methods to get arguments or to work directly with the properties of the class?

I am sure an example will help:

**Class with the method receiving parameters**

```
class distance {
    public function kilometersToMeters($kilometers) {
        return $kilometers * 1000;
    }
}

$obj = new distance();
echo $obj->kilometersToMeters(4);
```

**Class with the method working directly on the properties of the class**

```
class distance {
    private $kilometers;

    public function __construct($kilometers) {
        $this->kilometers = $kilometers;
    }

    public function kilometerToMeters() {
        return $this->kilometers * 1000;
    }
}

$obj = new distance(4);
echo $obj->kilometerToMeters();
```

Comment: Is it a property of the object (i.e. a person has a hand, leg, etc)? Then make it a class member variable. If it isn't but it something they would use (i.e. a tool like a hammer, etc) pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what kind of object you are trying to model. If you are building a distance calculator service which sole purpose is to convert between distances, then you could use your first approach, because your object wouldn't have any state, only behavior.

If you are modelling an object which has state and behavior, then the second form is more suitable, because you can initialize your object with the required fields, and validate those at construction. For instance:

```php
<?php
class Person {
    private $fullName;
    private $dateOfBirth;

    public function __construct($fullName, $dateOfBirth) {
        $this->checkInitializationVariables($fullName, $dateOfBirth);

        $this->fullName = $fullName;
        $this->dateOfBirth = $dateOfBirth;
    }

    public function getAge() {
        // calculate and return based on current date
    }

    public function getAgeAtDate($dateToCompare) {
        // calculate and return based on given date
    }

    private function checkInitializationVariables($fullName, $dateOfBirth) {
        if (empty($fullName)) {
            throw new Exception('Person must have a name.');
        }
        if (empty($dateOfBirth)) {
            throw new Exception('Person must have a date of birth.');
        }
    }
}

$person = new Person("John Doe", "01/01/2000");
echo $person->getAge();
echo $person->getAgeAtDate("01/01/2030");
```

Now you have an object which has state (name and birthday) and behavior (returns the age). You also have a check at initialization, to make sure your object is valid when it's created.